# Postfix mail server - forward email on failed delivery

Tags: postfix

Just wondering if there was a way to setup in Postfix mail server a 'redirect' email address if any emails fail to deliver to any of the intended recipients?

Comment: Why (what problem are you trying to solve)? - I can't imagine you *really* want a copy of every email where someone fat-fingered an address...

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT accept mail you cannot deliver.

If you cannot sastisfy this requirement for mail you wish to relay, don't relay the mail.